# how to output date and time from powershell to a file

Tags: windows, powershell

I can get current date and time in yyyy/mm/dd format in powershell. I want the output of this cmd to be put in text file.

Currently Command I run is

```
get-date -format yyyy/mm/dd
```

Works as expected but I when I try to redirect output to file I see error

```
get-date -format yyyy/mm/dd - o test.txt
```

The question might be trivial as I am new to powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Out-File

```
get-date -format yyyy/mm/dd | Out-File -FilePath C:\Date.txt
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `Out-File` will overwrite the full contents of the file, unless you add the parameter `-Append`.

Answer (score 1):

```
date -format yyyy/mm/dd >c:\date.txt
```

Overwrite txt file ^

```
date -format yyyy/mm/dd >>c:\date.txt
```

Append new line to txt file ^

Shorter and slightly more efficient method(s)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a recent change but mm is giving me minutes - I have had to use MM for months i.e.

```
date -format yyyy/MM/dd >> c:\date.txt
```